# How to subscribe to an event from different module/assembly?

Tags: mvvm, prism

I do this to publish/subscribe events within one module:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<StudioEnableEvent>().Publish((bool)arguments.ElementAt(1));
```

and then:

```
eventAggregator.GetEvent<StudioEnableEvent>().Subscribe(GetStudioEnableFromImport);
```

and StudioEnableEvent is simply:

```
 public class StudioEnableEvent : PubSubEvent<bool> 
    {
    }
```

Now I would like to do the same but for publisher and subscriber that are located in two different modules, and without need to reference the module assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach to this problem is to have another project in your solution that all module projects can reference. I like to call mine Core, or something along that line. There, I create the event classes, and that way I can share them across all modules. You can declare any other shared resources in this project, too.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this too. I already did this for interfaces that are shared across, but I was just wondering if there was some better way. Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of a better approach right off the cuff. I like these centralized projects; they are good for holding events, exceptions, simple services, etc.